# Converting SQL query with FORMAT command to use in entity framework core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have an SQL query:

```
SELECT 
                FORMAT(datetime_scrapped, 'MMMM-yy') [date], 
                count(FORMAT(datetime_scrapped, 'MMMM-yy')) as quantity 
                FROM scrap_log 
                GROUP BY FORMAT(datetime_scrapped, 'MMMM-yy')
```

It basically summarises all the entries in the scrap_log table by month/year and counts how many entries are in each month/year. Returns two columns (date and quantity). But I need to execute this in an ASP.NET core API using Entity Framework core. I tried using .fromSqlRaw(), but this expects all columns to be returned and so doesn't work.

I can find plenty of info on EF to implement group by and count etc... But I cannot find anything for the FORMAT(datetime, "MMMM-yy") part. Please could somebody explain to me how to do this?

EDIT: Seems already I appear to be going about this the wrong way in terms of efficiency. I will look into alternative solutions based on comments already made. Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: Don't do that in the first place. The performance of this query is *very* bad as it has to scan the *entire* table and group data without using any indexes. Use a Calendar table instead (a heavily indexed table prefilled with eg 20 years of dates with extra columns year, month, day, etc) and group by the Calendar table's Year and Month columns. This will use any indexes on the Calendar and `scraped` columns to speed up grouping. If you use filtering, the indexes will be used to select and group only the matching rows

Comment: With the current query, even if you tried to filter the data, the server would still have to scan the entire table to find matches. This means that even if you wanted to group a single months rows you'd still have to process every single row in the table

Comment: Updated question with edit, will look at a more efficient method of doing this, cheers.

Comment: Check [Creating a Dimension or Calendar Table in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Side note: it's nicer to group by `EOMONTH(datetime_scrapped)` as it remains a `datetime` value. Also, you should just do `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)`

Comment: If you want to summarize by month/year, then group by month and year (or year and month) instead of relying on string formatting (formatting when needed should be in application). e.g. `db.scrap_log.GroupBy(e => new { e.datetime_scrapped.Year, e.datetime_scrapped.Month }).Select(g => new { g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month, Count = g.Count() }`

Comment: Ivan's line of code works too. Would this still be inefficient in terms of SQL server processing?